# SQL Server : compare two string

Tags: sql-server, string, compare

I need to compare two strings and find difference. My first table is `t1.address`, second table `t2` contains suppliers it is address but from 3 columns `t2.adres + '  ' + t2.code + ' '  +t2.place` .

Example:

```
'Mlodziencza 36  03-655 Warszawa' t1.adres

'Mlodziencza 36  03-655 Warszawa' t2.adres+'  '+t2.code+' '+t2.place
```

Using my query I have 1120 rows in this year but most of them are the same only few are different. When I change in query `<>` to `=` in `t1.Kl_adres <> t2.adres+'  '+t2.code+' '+t2.place` `, I get 0 rows so they are all different and this is not true.

```
select t1.Kl_adres,t2.adres+'  '+t2.code+' '+t2.place,*  
from t1, t2 
where t1.Kl_code=t2.gruan+':'+t2.konto 
  and t1.year='2014'
  and t1.Kl_adres<>t2.adres+'  '+t2.code+' '+t2.place 
order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.Kl_adres, 
       t2.adres+'  '+t2.code+' '+t2.place, *  
FROM t1
  JOIN t2 
    ON t1.Kl_code=t2.gruan+':'+t2.konto 
WHERE
   t1.year='2014'
   and t1.Kl_adres<>t2.adres+'  '+t2.code+' '+t2.place
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. I got the same results as in my query.